# Implement friendly URL for badges

Tags: feature-request, badges, usability

I just earned the [asp.net-mvc-3](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-3) badge. I was the 84th to get this one.

Today the `URL` uses the badge Id to identify a given badge like this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/891?page=1
```

Id 891 points to [asp.net-mvc-3](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/891/asp-net-mvc-3).

Now I'd like to see who has the silver version of this badge. I tried changing the Id part to 890 or 892, but it's not sequentially. I'd have to guess the Id till I find the silver `asp.net-mvc-3` badge.

A `URL` format like this can solve it:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/asp.net-mvc-3?type=silver&page=1
```

I think it's doable.

---

Another possibility would be to show the other related versions/types of a badge as links. For example:

```
In the bronze badge page, offer a link to the silver and gold   versions.
In the silver badge page, offer a link to the bronze and gold   versions.
In the gold   badge page, offer a link to the bronze and silver versions.
```

Comment: The names of tags can change.  Ids tend not to.

Comment: @Makoto I'm pretty sure if the name of the tag changes it creates a new badge. When I merged a couple of tags here on Meta it re-awarded the new badge to everyone and revoked the old badge from everyone, which suggests that the badge is linked permanently to the ID. But then again, titles change and those are in the URL. ;)

Comment: That's not going to be simple as far as I can tell, and not sure it's worth the effort. You can see the tag badges "grouped" in [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags) and quickly reach the [bronze](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/891/asp-net-mvc-3), [silver](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/986/asp-net-mvc-3) and [gold](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1044/asp-net-mvc-3) versions: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly5I7.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the size of the page is probably starting to warrant something a little more robust than in-browser search, wouldn't [searching in the silver tag badges list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=silver) be easier than URL manipulation anyway?

I'm not sure I see the immediate benefit to changing the URLs, but I do think it would be reasonable to have links to the different levels on relevant badge pages.

Comment: Nice Tim... didn't know this was possible. I tried it at first but it only showed me the general silver badges. Using `tab=tags&filter=silver` allows searching for the badge easily.

Comment: Yeah, the navigation there is a little less obvious than it should be. It would be nice if the tag subfilter was more directly exposed.

Comment: I see. You first have to click `Badges`, then click the `silver` tab, then click the `Silver badge` to get to the list of all Silver badges. The same applies to the `Gold badge`.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi in the main [badges page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) there is a section "Tag Badges" where you can reach what Tim posted in one click. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Oops... that's even easier. There are so many options that we get confused at times. Thanks for sharing.