# Meaningful urls for tag badges

Tags: feature-request, badges, hyperlinks, tag-badges

Currently, tag badge urls are "secret". Let's make them "public" (predictable and meaningful).

Taking the SQL tag badges as an example:

- `Bronze SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/287/sql`
- `Silver SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/55/sql`
- `Golden SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/82/sql`

The numbers 287, 55 and 82 are essentially random and (AFAICT) not predictable. They are not even in ascending order that would correspond with the badge color order.

FYI, the `/sql` at the end is just sugar - the urls work with or without `/sql`.

#### Problem:

If you want to see who has a particular tag badge, and you don't know the [secret tag badge list url](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold) (I can't figure out how to get here without manual url manipulation) you can't guess the url - you have to find someone who has one, as follows:

- go to "Tags"
- look up the tag
- click it
- click "top users"
- click on the top user (who presumably has the badge)
- click on their badges
- find the badge and click it (may not be on the first page)

If this isn't ridiculous enough to find the gold badge url, if you want the bronze badge you can add several page refreshes to that list as you wade through their tag badges to find the bronze version, which will usually not be on the first page and you must hunt for it amongst the other tag badges.

This process is convoluted when it doesn't need to be, and even if you think this is a totally awesome state of affairs, why not have a meaningful url anyway?

#### Proposal:

Make the tag urls like this:

- `https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/sql/bronze`
- `https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/sql/silver`
- `https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/sql/gold`

You could add a landing page for the tag that displays summary stats for all three colours at:

- `https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/sql`

Comment: Related: [Implement friendly URL for badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192401)