# Can we have a working route if we use the id from the Badges table?

Tags: feature-request, badges, hyperlinks

**tl;dr** I would like to have a route to a badge based on the id in SEDE.

In SEDE we have a table Badges(Id, UserId, Name, Date, Class, TagBased).

For me the first [few badges](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/308394) look like this:

```
Id      | UserId | Name           | Date              | Class | TagBased
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1361955 | 578411 | Autobiographer |2011-01-19 17:15:25|  3    | false
1367877 | 578411 | Teacher        |2011-01-21 15:16:02|  3    | false
1369965 | 578411 | Editor         |2011-01-22 13:47:17|  3    | false
```

I really want to create a link to those badges with functionality provided in SEDE. Unfortunately the link on Stack Overflow for my [teacher badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1/teacher?userid=578411) is

```
https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1/teacher?userid=578411
```

We don't have that magic 1 between badges and teacher, which is confirmed by [Tim Stone in The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3378397#3378397). It wouldn't all be that bad if those numbers were stable across the network (at least for the named badges) but [they aren't](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges-by-ids)

> Note that badge ids are not constant across sites, and thus should be looked up via the /badges method. A badge id on a single site is, however, guaranteed to be stable.

I would have to write a script for the API to retrieve all badges from all sites and convert that to a SQL insert script...and that needs to be updated weekly to reflect any new badges....

This scenario would become much easier if there was a route that accepts the id from the badge table and would render the specific badge for the user. Something like this:

[`http://stackoverflow/badge/1367877`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1/teacher?userid=578411)

Does such route [maybe already exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76569/158100) but is it not yet [revealed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-exchange)? If this doesn't exist can this be considered to be added? Or add the master-badgeid to the badge table? Either solution will work and enable us to render a working link from SEDE for badges.

Until this is implemented we can use some javascript to get the badges from the StackAPI as shown [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254596/158100).

<sup>There are two requests ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192401/implement-friendly-url-for-badges),[2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219615/meaningful-urls-for-tag-badges)) that ask for different behavior of the badge url but they don't solve this problem. My request doesn't invalidate those request.</sup>

Comment: The ID currently in the data dump is drawn from the internal table that maps users to badges. So it'd be easy enough to map one of those IDs to a userID and badgeID (for a given site), but I'm not aware of any route that currently does this. Depending on what you're trying to do, you might find that [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) is a better tool for this.

Comment: @Shog9 I was hoping to create links for the badgenames in this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254596/158100. If I have the badgeid that will solve it as well

Answer (score 3):

While I cannot provide order, I can provide a [table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369665/is-there-a-table-of-badge-ids-for-all-stack-exchange-sites/) where the badge IDs are easy to look up manually or programmatically.