# Include badge names as query strings on the badge pages

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, badges

As it stands, each badge is assigned a number that you can access it by at `{sitename}/help/badges/{number}`.

However, there's no way to access the badge by its name:

```
{sitename}/help/badges/guru
```

Integers would be fine, however, they vary depending on site:

For example, on Stack Overflow, [badge number `58` is the tag for vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/58), whereas on Code Review, [badge number `58` is the sportsmanship tag](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/58).

It might also be good for the global tags (tags every site, even beta sites) to use the same IDs and have each tag varying.

Comment: Consolidating badge IDs across sites would be a huge hassle as badges get added at different times. If we added a new badge to all sites today, it would have a different ID on every single site because every site is at a different increment in the database. Making them all match simply isn't worth the effort.

Comment: That's why the title of the post isn't "_consolidate the title_" :-(

Comment: Hmm. Why would, for example, sceptics need a vb.net tag?

Comment: @DavidPostill what are you talking about? the vb.net is a content specific tag, my point is talking about how the same badge numbers feature different content over different tags.

Comment: My point is that not all sites have all badges. So you would have holes in the numbering system ... which makes the database code more complicated (notwithstanding the renumbering issue mentioned by @animuson)

Comment: I don't believe there are any *tags* that are on every site; there are tags that are on every *meta* site, however. (Whether those should be consolidated is another matter; that would probably be doable, but not terribly useful.)

Comment: I have a somewhat similar request [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254605/158100) but I didn't consider to use the badgename in the route.