# On privileges vote up page, badges should link to the badge page

Tags: feature-request, badges, privileges, help-center

Near the end of the [privileges, vote up page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up), there is a mention of five voting-related badges.

On the page, the badges are not clickable.  It would be nice if they were clickable and link to the respective pages for each of those badges.

Comment: this might be technically difficult as most of the help pages are static across all sites, while the link to the badges isn't stable. The id for each badge changes per-site. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254605/can-we-have-a-working-route-if-we-use-the-id-from-the-badges-table

Comment: Also, on the right side, it says: "This privilege - Indicate when questions and answers are useful - ✅ You earned this privilege". Gerrit (and me) should have green check marks next to the voting badges that we have earned, mine are missing.